Optimization of Multivariable Functions Using Lagrange Multipliers
Q.) Given the function  $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$  find its local minima and maxima to the constrain $x+y+z = 1$
How do I properly set up the equations using the method of Lagrange multipliers for this problem?

Hi, welcome to MSE! Per the community guidelines, please also include what you've tried thus-far to solve the problem.

Basically, your Lagrange multiplier will be an equation of connection equalized to zero: $ \phi(x,y,z) = x+y+z-1 $
So your Lagrange function will be $L(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2 + \lambda(x+y+z-1)$. Then you take a derivative with respect to each variable(with respect to $\lambda$ too!) and find a stationary point.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        L'_x=2x+\lambda = 0 \\
        L'_y=2y+\lambda = 0 \\
        L'_z=2z+\lambda = 0 \\
        x+y+z=1
    \end{cases}\
\end{equation}
Hope this answers your question)
